# JavaScript not showing hidden picture

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a problem with this JavaScript method. I just want that when I click on one link, it shows the hidden picture, and when I click it one more time it hides it and so on. But it's not working properly. Here's the code check it by yourself and try to help me with this thing.

```
<head>
<style>
    .hide {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>


<a data-img='sloth-pic' id='sloth' href='#'>Sloth</a>

<img class='hide' id='sloth-pic' src='https://static-secure.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Education/Pix/pictures/2013/1/17/1358446759827/A-three-toed-tree-sloth-h-008.jpg' style='width:304px;height:228px;'>

 <script>

    var sloth = document.getElementById("sloth");
    var slothPic = document.getElementById("sloth");

    sloth.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if(slothPic.className === "hide") {
            sloth.className = "";
        } else if(sloth.className === ""){
            slothPic.className = "hide";
        }
    });

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: As a side note I would recommend you have a look at jQuery, as this will make things like this a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used wrong `id` attributes in your JavaScript.

You can make it toggle using *ternary* operators.

Try this:

```js
var sloth = document.getElementById("sloth");
var slothPic = document.getElementById("sloth-pic");
sloth.addEventListener("click", function() {
  slothPic.className = (slothPic.className == "hide") ? "" : "hide";
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a data-img='sloth-pic' id='sloth' href='#'>Sloth</a>
<br>
<img class='hide' id='sloth-pic' src='https://static-secure.guim.co.uk/sys-images/Education/Pix/pictures/2013/1/17/1358446759827/A-three-toed-tree-sloth-h-008.jpg' style='width:304px;height:228px;'>
```

Comment: Yeah obvious stupid mistake haha, it's just a thing that I'm tired tonight. Thanks btw for the respond and answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/jorge182/cor14ze5/6/

```
    sloth.addEventListener("click", function() {

            if($('#sloth-pic').hasClass('hide')){

                $('#sloth-pic').removeClass('hide')
            }else{
               $('#sloth-pic').addClass('hide')
            }
        })
```

Comment: I´m using jQuery for this example.

Comment: How about `toggleClass` ? `jQuery` is not tagged in the question!

Comment: Yeah obvious stupid mistake in naming id attribute haha, it's just a thing that I'm tired tonight. Thanks btw for the answer! I learned something new in jQuery. It's great.

Comment: As @RayonDabre said you can use toggleClass method, is the short way.              sloth.addEventListener("click", function() {
         $('#sloth-pic').toggleClass('hide')
    });

Answer (score 0):

I think you just made some mistakes with the use of sloth and sloth-pic. It should be like this:

```
var sloth = document.getElementById("sloth");
var slothPic = document.getElementById("sloth-pic");

sloth.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(slothPic.className === "hide") {
        slothPic.className = "";
    } else if(sloth.className === ""){
        slothPic.className = "hide";
    }
});
```

You can find a working example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/nLn23r5j/

Comment: Yeah obvious stupid mistake haha, it's just a thing that I'm tired tonight. Thanks btw for the respond and answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just a couple lines of Jquery, see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7oe5kh9L/55/

```
  $("#sloth").click(function() {
    $(".hide").toggleClass("show")
  });
```

css

```
.hide {display: none;}

.show {display: inline;}
```

Comment: This is also helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to add more classes to the image use this code.

```js
var sloth = document.getElementById("sloth");
var slothPic = document.getElementById("sloth-pic");

sloth.addEventListener("click", function() {
  toggleClass(slothPic, 'hide');
  return false;
});

function toggleClass(element, className){
    if (!element || !className){
        return;
    }

    var classString = element.className, nameIndex = classString.indexOf(className);
    if (nameIndex == -1) {
        classString += ' ' + className;
    }
    else {
        classString = classString.substr(0, nameIndex) + classString.substr(nameIndex+className.length);
    }
    element.className = classString;
}
```

```css
    .hide {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<a data-img='sloth-pic' id='sloth' href='#'>Sloth</a>

<img class='hide' id='sloth-pic' src='http://www.miamammausalinux.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/stackoverflow2.png' style='width:304px;height:228px;'>
```

Comment: This is awesome and it will be a lot helpful in my further work. Thanks, I appreciate it!